# Non-cancellable futures returned by a thread-pool. Do they exist?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, future

I'm currently implementing a service that works in a concurrent setting and that has as operations a bunch of blocking methods.

I would like to change that so they return a `Future<?>` instead and it's up to the client to decide whether he wants to execute `get()` and block the thread or not. The problem is that `Future<?>` brings baggage, ie, it is possible to invoke cancellation on a future. But if that were to actually happen then it would most probably break my service's invariants.

Is there any easy way to make a thread-pool return non-cancellable futures? Currently, the only solution I'm seeing is wrapping the thread-pool future's into a future of mine that will throw an `UnsupportedException` if some attempts to cancel the operation. Or just return an object of my own, but I'd like to KISS if possible.

Comment: You mean your service has bunch of blocking methods as operations. So an operation say `operaionOne` will perform some blocking methods and then return result?

Comment: What are you worried about with the wrapping the thread pool's `Future` solution?

Comment: @akhil_mittal: yes. I want them to not block when someone invokes those methods.

Comment: @durron597: I was just wondering if there's some already existing solution so I don't have to roll out my own CancellableFuture implementation (I know it's easy..).

Comment: @devouredelysium It would probably take 5 minutes to wrap it properly in the right IDE, that's why I'm wondering what you're concerned about.

Comment: It takes less than 5 minutes. But it also takes less than 5 minutes to roll out my own ArrayList implementation, and I still prefer to know there already is one available than hand-rolling one every time. This seems like a recurrent  issue and I was wondering if there was anything already available, just that.

Comment: Agrre with @devouredelysium, if you like to KISS, just wrap it!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you fear too much. I see two VERY simple solutions:

1. decorate (wrap) the default [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) and override in your ExecutorService the [newTaskFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#newTaskFor%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) method returning your new class.
2. do nothing, i.e do not cancel any work in your `Callable`s or `Runnable`s. In order to make your life easier you could take a look at [Guava's uninterruptibles](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Uninterruptibles.html).